# A question about ring of endormorphisms $End(M)$ of module $M / R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, category-theory, modules

If $M$ is an $R$-module then you can consider its ring of endomorphisms, $End(M)$. You get a natural $End(M)$-module structure on $M$, where scalar multiplication is given by $u \cdot m := u(m)$. Does this new module have any significance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose the answer is "yes" because it appears in classical ring theory in places, for example in the [double centralizer theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_centralizer_theorem).

It is the most natural way to make a module into a bimodule.

Comment: I would add *Morita theory* as an important buzzword.